# What does := denote within the context of a placeholder

Tags: mysql, sql

This is probably a dumb question to those that know, but here goes.

Experimenting with using a placeholder in a query. I find that the following works:

```
SELECT day, @dy:=CAST( CASE day
                         WHEN 'Su' THEN 1
                         WHEN 'Mo' THEN 2
                         WHEN 'Tu' THEN 3
                         WHEN 'Wed' THEN 4
                         WHEN 'Th' THEN 5
                         WHEN 'Fr' THEN 6
                         WHEN 'Sa' THEN 7
                     END AS UNSIGNED) as dayofweek 
 FROM `Schedule_Repetition` WHERE repetition_Key='426';
```

**But this does not work**

```
SELECT day, @dy=CAST( CASE day
                         WHEN 'Su' THEN 1
                         WHEN 'Mo' THEN 2
                         WHEN 'Tu' THEN 3
                         WHEN 'Wed' THEN 4
                         WHEN 'Th' THEN 5
                         WHEN 'Fr' THEN 6
                         WHEN 'Sa' THEN 7
                     END AS UNSIGNED) as dayofweek 
 FROM `Schedule_Repetition` WHERE repetition_Key='426';
```

I see all sorts of examples of placeholders some of which use `@P=.....` and others which use `@P:=.......`  Please could someone explain what the **:=** denotes and why the syntax varies and or point the way to the documentation which explains to use of **:=**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:=` is an [assignment operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value). The information below is from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value) on dev.mysql.com.

> Assignment operator. Causes the user variable on the left hand side of
>   the operator to take on the value to its right. The value on the right
>   hand side may be a literal value, another variable storing a value, or
>   any legal expression that yields a scalar value, including the result
>   of a query (provided that this value is a scalar value).

The difference between `=` and `:=`:

> = Assign a value (as part of a SET statement, or as part of the SET clause in an UPDATE statement) 
>   :=    Assign a value
>
> Unlike =, the := operator is never interpreted as a comparison
>   operator. This means you can use := in any valid SQL statement (not
>   just in SET statements) to assign a value to a variable.

Check out the [full list of operators on dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html).

Comment: thanks for those documentation links (not quite sure how I missed those) and many thanks for such a clear response.